# How to make a specific object from an ordinary object for use in a mongodb $set parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object

How can I transform this object in JavaScript:

```
let object = {
    a: {
        b: 12
        c: {
           d: 13
        }
    }
}
```

Into this:

```
let object = {"a.b": 12, "a.c.d": 13}
```

I want to modify object and use it like a $set param in mongodb in updateOne method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.entries` to iterate over each [key, value] pair using `flatMap`, and recursively get to the leaves of the object tree, building up the path to each leaf in the `p` array. Once a leaf is found, use `join` to turn the path array into a dotted path string. `flatMap` is used to ensure that a flat array of [key, value] pairs are returned, instead of a nested array. Finally, we use `Object.fromEntries` to turn the list of pairs into an array.

```js
let data = {
  a: {
    b: 12,
    c: {
      d: 13
    }
  },
  e: {
    f: {
      g: 6
    }
  }
}

const f = (v, p=[]) => typeof v === 'object' ? 
  Object.entries(v).flatMap(([k, v]) => f(v, [...p, k])) : [[p.join('.'), v]]

console.log(Object.fromEntries(f(data)))
```